# Rails building predesigned database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner in Rails and I have a complete database designed with a database design tool. (For a startup so quite confidential)

Can I write all the tables and their columns straigth into the migration file and then migrate or should I run the >> rails generate model ...    for every table in my database?

And what about the join tables? Do I need to create them to or do they get created when I write the table classes for association?

I have some experience in MySQL from school so things are a litle strange switching to Rails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read more about [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), specially for [join-table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-join-table), [association-tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration).

For your question to create all databases, and all tables in one migration file, I think that is valid, but that is bad, you can write code as the following:

```
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create :table_1 do |t1|
      t1.string :name
    end
    create :table_2 do |t2|
      t2.string :name
    end
    # this for join table
    create_join_table :table_1, :table_2
    # this for associations
     add_reference :table_1, :table_2, index: true
  end
end
```

But this tables will create in your database that is called `database.yml` file, and you can see your tables using mysql, but if you want to use active-record functions as(new, create, update, save, validations, ...), so you'll need to create model for these tables

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate model` is just a template generator to create

- a migration file under db/migrate
- a model file under app/models with some template
- some related test files

All of these can be done manually.

In your case, you can create your migration file (for building the tables) and model file separately, no need to stick with `generate` function.

Comment: Thanks mate, that clears up my confusion about the generate command ;)

Answer (score 0):

(1)Can I write all the tables and their columns straight into the migration file and then migrate?

Yes, you can, but I would not recommend it. Because at first you need to create migration files in the db/migrate directory and definition migration class by yourself, I think it is very boring. If Rails can help you do this , you doesn't need to do it yourself, but you should understand how migration works. Secondly, create you needed tables at present unless just a test or small rails application, because customer(maybe yourself) needs and expectations are changing. Perhaps the end you doesn't use some tables at all or change tables frequently.

(2)should I run the >> rails generate model ... for every table in my database?

You are a beginner in Rails, so am I. I suggest you use the rails generate command to create tables, models, controllers..., this is the foundation of Rails learning, and it is very convenience.

(3)And what about the join tables? Do I need to create them to or do they get created when I write the table classes for association?

You can create it by yourself, can also use rails generate command.

[Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) can provide you with direction and help.